# Tensorflow Reshape and Pad

Tags: tensorflow

I have a 2D `Tensor` with each row containing a single datapoint. Size of data is not known at graph build time. I need to transform the data Tensor into a batch for RNN as 3D Tensor with new elements padded with zeros. Not sequence lengths nor number of sequences are known at graph build time. Sequence lengths is a `tf.placeholder` and data Tensor is an output of previous TF ops. How do I turn this

```
# Data
[[1 1]
 [1 1]
 [2 2]
 [3 3]
 [3 3]
 [3 3]]
# Sequence lengths
[2 1 3]
```

into this

```
[[[1 1]
  [1 1]
  [0 0]]

 [[2 2]
  [0 0]
  [0 0]]

 [[3 3]
  [3 3]
  [3 3]]]
```

`tf.split`+`tf.pad`+`tf.concat` approach doesn't work since number of sequences is not known at graph build time and `tf.split` requires `num_or_size_splits` argument to have fixed shape.

`tf.dynamic_partition`+`tf.stack` approach with partition indices generated with `tf.while_loop` from sequence lengths doesn't work since `num_partitions` argument of `tf.dynamic_partition` needs to be fixed integer, not a Tensor, and number of sequences is not known at graph build time.

`tf.scatter_update`+`tf.reshape` approach with row indices and row values generated with `tf.while_loop` from sequence lengths doesn't work since `tf.scatter_update` requires a `Variable` and `Variable` requires a fixed size (size of data Tensor is not known at graph build time).

I could fix batch size at graph build time but that leads to need for rebuilding the graph when batch size changes and thus I would not like to do it this way.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: I've just asked a similar question and got an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409488/tensorflow-tensor-reshape-and-pad-with-zeros-at-the-end-of-some-rows?sgp=2